# One Half of Ten; A Riddle

Tags: riddle

I keep on walking; my toe is my sole
My movement persists, my body a hole
My neighbors support, as I support them
You could say I look like one half of ten

Tree is my father, my maker a man
One point to hurt me; I'm not a huge fan
What happens above me, remains the same
What happens below me will not remain

A maze of paths means I am good to go
The smoother the worse to keep things down low
Do not think I'll last, even if you trust
Get a new neighbor, that's surely a must

Comment: Could be a shadow?

Comment: @jwize, your answer is just a shadow of the truth ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you are...

> ..a car wheel/tire?

I keep on walking

> The movement of the wheel.

my toe is my sole

> Bending a shoe's toe around to the sole will make it round like a tire.

My movement persists

> When you push a wheel, it keeps on moving.

my body a hole

> Wheels usually have a hole in the middle.

My neighbors support, as I support them

> Car wheels work together as a team.

You could say I look like one half of ten

> One half of ten is 0 which looks like a wheel.

Tree is my father, my maker a man

> Earlier versions of wheels used to be made of wood. Also, car tires are made of rubber and natural rubber comes from trees.

One point to hurt me; I'm not a huge fan

> Maybe a nail? Can cause harm (deflate) the car tire.

What happens above me, remains the same
What happens below me will not remain

> The car stays the same while the wheels are moving but the road changes.

A maze of paths means I am good to go

> The tread of a tire looks like a maze of paths. When it's clear and not worn off, the car is good to go.

The smoother the worse to keep things down low

> When the tire gets smoother, it becomes slippery making the car dangerous to drive.

Do not think I'll last, even if you trust
Get a new neighbor, that's surely a must

> Car wheels get changed often.

Comment: Rubber comes from trees. A maze of paths is the tread. When it wears out the tire is smooth.

Comment: @DrXorile Makes sense.

Comment: @DrXorile Some rubber comes from trees, but tires are mostly made from synthetic rubber these days - still, close enough.

Comment: Well done @AhmedAbdelhameed, you are correct, it's a car's tyre. Not all the sentence breakdowns are correct: DrXorile is correct about the tread, and smooth tyre, and that rubber comes from trees. Also, my toe is my sole is a bit more visual: bending a shoe's toe around to the sole will effectively make it round like a tyre, a tyre has no beginning and no end as it is round, so the toe and the sole is one and the same, like a never-ending shoe.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed will you be so kind as to edit your answer, then I'll accept it

Comment: @nine9 Done :-)

Answer (score 5):

You are

> a cart wheel.

Explanation:

> It keeps on walking, toe is it's sole.
>  
>  It's body is largely a hole.
>  
>  Other cartwheels are its neighbour.
>  
>  It looks like 0, i.e. one half of ten.
>  
>  It's made up of wood, which comes from tree and is made into wheel by man.
>  
>  Above it is cart, which remains the same. 
>  Below is road, which keeps on changing.

Comment: Welcome to the Puzzling Stack Exchange community! Please hide your answer using the >! tag (spoiler) when you write down yout ideas, so others will have a chance to find their own solutions. Thanks! :)

Comment: @user57398, good guess! I was looking for car tyre, where the tree association has to do with rubber coming from trees. One of the only clues which doesn't match is the maze of paths and smooth sentence, which describes the tread of the tyre, and the danger of having smooth tyres

Answer (score 3):

Answere might be

> pair of slippers

As it is a

1.

> slipper it’s toe is it’s sole

2.

> earlier days riots if the trees used to make slippers

3.What happens above me remains the same

> as we wear our toe marks remains forever and the below it changes

Answer (score 2):

The solution is

> A wooden shoe.
>
>  It protects 5 toes - 1/2 of ten, the bottom wears out quickly, it works better if you have two.